# How the Microsoft Store handles the app certifications?

Tags: uwp, publishing

I'm developing a `UWP` application. For creating a sideloaded build, I'm using a test certificate to sign the app, generated by the Visual Studio. My first question: is there any way to renew this certificate so my users should NOT uninstall the old build and reinstall the app with the new certificate? (I tried to enter the same subject when creating the new certificate, but it says that it's untrusted and should be added to the trusted root certificates manually.)

Secondly, I didn't find anything about how the Microsoft Store handles the certificates when I publish the app... When I associate the app with the store, I receive a new certificate (which is also valid for just one year).

- Is that certificate installed automatically when the users install the app from the Microsoft Store? (If yes, then how would it be extended after that one year passes?)
- Or, when I publish, it will be changed to another one, which is always trusted? (I couldn't find the signature of any app installed from the store to check this)

Thirdly: Is that somehow possible to install on top of a previously installed sideloaded build, another build of the same application directly from the Microsoft Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My first question: is there any way to renew this certificate so my users should NOT uninstall the old build and reinstall the app with the new certificate?

No, you need to reinstall the certificate to renew it.

> Is that certificate installed automatically when the users install the app from the Microsoft Store? (If yes, then how would it be extended after that one year passes?)

Yes, the store will handle the certificate process automatically. You don't need to worry about the certificate if you installed the app from the store.

> Is that somehow possible to install on top of a previously installed sideloaded build, another build of the same application directly from the Microsoft Store?

No, the certificate that the store generated when the installation is different from the certificate that you generated when you creating a sideloaded app. So the system will consider these two packages as two different apps.